# C# XNA Draw Multiple Sprites at Random Position

Tags: c#, xna

I am creating a game in XNA and wish to have multiple sprites drawn at random positions. The problem I have is that the sprites appear to redraw at a new position each time the Draw() function is called. This is making them flash around the screen randomly. I want them to draw once and stay in that position.

I have created a List to hold the sprites:

```
List<Texture2D> kiwis = new List<Texture2D>();
```

Then in the LoadContent() function I have added sprites to the list:

```
 kiwi = Content.Load<Texture2D>("Sprites/kiwi");
 if (kiwis.Count() < 4)
 {
      kiwis.Add(kiwi);
 }
```

Then in Draw(), I have:

```
foreach (Texture2D kiwi in kiwis)
{
    spriteBatch.Draw(kiwi, kiwiPosition, Color.White);                                          
}
```

This is the kiwiPosition Vector2:

```
 kiwiPosition = new Vector2(random.Next(30, 610), random.Next(30, 450));
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Make a `kiwi` (fruit?) class, give it a position, and texture, then when you load it, give it its position and texture

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to my comment, insert and replace with the following as required

```
public class Fruit
{
     private Vector2 pos;
     public Vector2 Position
     {
         get{return pos;}
         set{pos = value;}
     }
     public Texture2D Texture {get;set;}

     public Fruit(Texture2D tex, Vector2 pos)
     {
         Position = pos;
         Texture = tex;
     }
}
List<Fruit> kiwis = new List<Fruit>();

kiwi = Content.Load<Texture2D>("Sprites/kiwi");
if (kiwis.Count() < 4)
{
    kiwis.Add(new Kiwi(kiwiTex, 
                       new Vector2(random.Next(30, 610), random.Next(30, 450)));
}

foreach (Fruit kiwi in kiwis)
{
    spriteBatch.Draw(kiwi.Texture, kiwi.Position, Color.White);  
}
```

---

The difference between this approach and your current approach, is that your position will only get set once instead of once per frame

Comment: It drew all the kiwis in the same position on the screen.

Comment: This is because most computers are fast enough to generate the same "random" number, when executing every command. This is because Random is time-based. And nowadays computers are so fast, that even though Random gets a new number every 10 millisecond or so, it's not fast enough. 99% of machines will have executed that entire code in much less than 10 milliseconds. Basically you'll have to find some way to generate it without using just Random.